# R Simmer check the max wait time when joining queue

Tags: r, simulation

I'm hoping this is an easy question!
I can see that there is a function get_queue_count which is almost what I need, but I don't need the number in the queue, I need to know the max time spent in the queue by any individual. I can then send the customers down another trajectory if the max queue time is over a variable.

Any help, as always, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a custom function solved this. Admittedly I need to clean this and I'm sure someone could make it a lot faster but there we go.

```
fn_queue_time <- function() {
qt <- sim %>%
get_mon_attributes() %>%
filter(key == "q_start" | key == "q_end") %>%
group_by(name) %>%
mutate(count = n()) %>%
filter(count == 1) %>%
pivot_wider(id_cols = name, names_from= key, values_from = time) %>%
mutate(q = simmer::now(sim) - q_start) %>%
ungroup() %>%
summarise(m = max(q)) %>%
pull()
}

arrive <- c(1:5)

traj <- trajectory("traj") %>%
log_("arrive") %>%
set_attribute(keys = "q_start", values = function() {now(sim)}) %>%
log_(function() {paste("Q time: ", fn_queue_time())}) %>%
branch(function() ifelse(fn_queue_time() >= 5, 1, 2),
continue = F,
trajectory() %>%
log_("q too long, offered alternative") %>%

renege_in(5,
out = trajectory() %>%
log_("alternative accepted") %>% set_attribute(keys = "q_end", values = function() {now(sim)}) %>%
set_attribute(keys = "alternative accepted", values = function() {now(sim)})
) %>%
seize("resource") %>%
log_("service") %>%
renege_abort() %>%
set_attribute(keys = "q_end", values = function() {now(sim)}) %>%
timeout(10) %>%
release("resource"),
trajectory() %>%
log_("norm") %>%
renege_in(5, out = trajectory() %>%
log_("reneg") %>% set_attribute(keys = "q_end", values = function() {now(sim)}) %>%
set_attribute(keys = "reneg", values =function({now(sim)})) %>%
seize("resource") %>%
log_("service") %>%
renege_abort() %>%
set_attribute(keys = "q_end", values = function() {now(sim)}) %>%
timeout(10) %>%
log_("service end") %>%
release("resource"))

sim <- simmer("sim") %>%
add_generator("cust",traj, at(arrive), mon = 2) %>%
add_resource("resource", 1)


sim %>%
run(until = 800)
```